# Error on build command del exited with code 1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget

We are using local Nuget packages and after a merge I had problems with them so I decided to uninstall and reinstall them. But after that I always get this error on build

> The command "del D:\Project path" exited with code 1.

I tried completely uninstalling the packages, changing the versions but the error is still there on every build attempt.

Comment: According to the error log, that seem like you have custom build task or build event in your project. Could you please check your project about the custom task or build event, make sure it hat it can be executed correctly?

Comment: Yeah. I found the event and removed it and now everything is fine.

Comment: Since you have resolved your problem, I have convert my comment to answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem. You can mark it answer if it help you, and you can also add comment for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The command "del D:\Project path" exited with code 1.

According to the error log, that seem like you have **custom build task or build event** in your project.

You can check your project about the custom task or build event, make sure it can be executed correctly or you can remove it, then build the project again, check if it works fine.